# H0w do I add a delay to the launch of an application via RocketDock Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, command-line-arguments, delay

I have a shortcut in Rocketdock that will trigger my screensaver using flipss. However, the screensaver starts right away and the dock won't auto-hide until the mouse is no longer hovering over it. This causes the dock to be visible whilst the screensaver is active. I need a few seconds to move the mouse.

I have tried using the timeout command in both the TARGET then the ARGUMENT field, and both return errors. The argument field has the `/start` flag and I'm not sure how to add other values. I need to introduce a 3 second delay before flipss activates. What is the correct syntax for accomplishing this?

Comment: For what OS?  here is an example one user worked out for windows http://superuser.com/a/680361/98855

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm running Windows 7, I actually saw that post and attempted to use the commands shown in the example but it resulted in errors. I'm not sure if it was my lack of knowledge about proper syntax or that the commands are in a RocketDock shortcut and not a normal Windows shortcut.

Comment: try and get testing in the most simplified manner, test in a CMD first, then test in the dock.  The "start" flag is likely another command that sets an item off to run seperate from its base window, having it on might not help. Do simple things like "Notepad.exe && Calc.exe"  and see if you get anywhere?  <--No quotes, but use quotes for whole file paths and commands when spaces exist.